# Why not send out probes to speed up the search for the Fleming?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Force of Nature" (Season 7 Episode 9), the Enterprise-D needs to search for a missing ship in a region in which "Tetrion radiation" impairs sensors and communications. Worf asks whether they couldn't send out reconnaissance probes to supplement their sensor sweeps, and LaForge tells him that won't be "very effective", since the interference will make it difficult to stay in contact with the probes. And so, they reject that idea.

But - why? Why can't the Enterprise send out a bunch of probes, have them move at the slow speed they need to be in for a "Level 1 search", then go pick them up at a faster speed?

Notes:

- The question disregards what happens later in the episode.
- My suggested alternative does not require the probes to enter warp or make any round-trips.

Comment: Surely the probe(s) wouldn't make it through the Plot Purposes Nebula intact?

Comment: Or maybe all the probes are offline because of routine maintenance by Ensign Narrative Convenience?

Comment: If the Enterprise  travels to the place where the probes are, then there's no need to send a probe there

Comment: @Valorum: The Enterprise (+ probes) need to cover a certain path, or area, at a slow speed. With more probes, it can be covered quicker.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie: If that were the case, LaForge would have mentioned that rather than "it would be difficult to communicate with them".

Comment: @einpoklum - If I'm at point A and I send you off to point B to see what's there, but I can't tell what you've seen **unless I go to point B to ask you**, what was the point of sending you in the first place?

Comment: They're looking for a ship which is missing, possibly destroyed. If they send out a probe and they're not in contact with it, if it goes missing or is destroyed, how would they know? They'll be no better off than before they launched it.

Comment: @Cadence: 1. They'll know when they get to where the were supposed to pick up the probe. Which, on average, would be well before they would otherwise scan the area the probe had scanned. 2. They would be better off, because they would be able to eliminate the areas scanned by other probes and know they need to focus on the area with the destroyed/missing probe.

Comment: @Valorum: The point is that the Enterprise can get from point A to point B quickly, but it can't scan the range between those points quickly. So the traveling part is out of the equation, it is the slow-moving coverage of the range that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few different elements at play here.

A) The probes won't be able to remain in continuous contact with the ship, which means that they'll need to be collected, sensor logs downloaded and then analysed. Without the Enterprise's advanced computer and on-board sensors, the probe could easily overlook the Fleming and give a false impression that an area has been thoroughly searched.

B) The sensors on the probes are much more likely to be affected by the interference that's blocking the Enterprise sensors, further limiting their usefulness.

C) If the Enterprise needs to keep diverting in order to collect the probes, the ship's time could be better spent on a more effective *individual* search pattern with their more powerful sensors

D) Geordi doesn't have time to configure a bunch of probes when he and Data could better spend their time doing the multi-phasic buffer thing with the Enterprise sensors.

---

Assuming the sensors on the probes are 10 times less effective than the main sensors, then the Enterprise would still end up following basically the same search pattern (e.g. in order to collect the probes), except with the added complication of now having parts of their search that they couldn't 100% trust.

[image]

---

> **WORF:** *Could we send out reconnaissance probes to supplement the sensors?*
>
> **GEORDI:** *They won't be very effective. The interference will make it difficult to maintain contact with the probes; the best we can do is to try increasing the sensor efficiency. beat; to Picard) We're installing multi-phase buffers on all the sensor modules. It should help a little.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Force of Nature - Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/261.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: Also, everyone enjoys telling Worf "no"

Comment: "Assuming the sensors on the probes are 10 times less effective than the main sensors" <- That's the main assumption in your answer. Which sounds reasonable, but then you would expect LaForge to give _that_ as the reason to reject Worf's suggestion.

Comment: @einpoklum - Well we certainly wouldn't expect them to be *as* powerful as the Enterprise's sensors. Even if they were 75% as effective, the same reasoning would hold true. Unless you had fifty of them ready to go, you couldn't achieve the same coverage that you can get from two days of flying around, *since you'd have to go and collect them*.

Comment: Well, I would disagree, because (B) has no basis beyond (A), and (C) is not true, i.e. it just needs to make a pass at the end to collect the probes - but that pass is _fast_, and negligible/very short relative to the time taken by scanning.

Comment: @einpoklum - You seem to be trying to justify a headcanon reason. La Forge is the expert here and he says no dice.

Comment: Valorum: 1. He says "no dice because X", but X is not an issue. So, probably, 2. The writers just seem to have made a mistake and put it in La Forge's mouth.

Comment: @einpoklum - As I've said previously, if you have to go and collect the probes, what's the point of sending a probe?

Comment: You can collect the probes very quickly; but the scanning is slow. So you use many slow scanners, to parallelize, then collect them all.

Comment: @einpoklum - You're assuming it'll take zero time to configure the probes, send them off, collect them and then analyse their (presumably sub-standard) results. Geordi, the expert in these matters, thinks there's a better use of their time and resources. There's no error here, except in your own headcanon

Comment: Geordi thinks the worst problem worth mentioning with the drones approach is the inability to stay in contact with them. So, it seems like he's not concerned with the amount of time it would take to configure and launch the probes.

Comment: @einpoklum - Its a 'missing ship, potential rescue' scenario. I'm guessing they want to be prompt about it